# did any one able to import azure storage blob using pulumi. if so please let me know the command?

Tags: pulumi, pulumi-azure

I am trying to import the azure storage blob state in to pulumi using PULUMI CLI.

### tried below cmd

pulumi import --yes  azure-native:storage:Blob testblob

it thrown error with below.

error: Preview failed: "resourceGroupName" not found in resource state

please let me know if any one is able to successfully import the azure storage blob resource in to pulumi.

thanks,
kumar

### tried below cmd

pulumi import --yes  azure-native:storage:Blob testblob

it thrown error with below.

error: Preview failed: "resourceGroupName" not found in resource state

expected result: to import successfully
actual result: import failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [docs for a Blob resource](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/storage/blob/) there's an [import section](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/azure-native/api-docs/storage/blob/#import) (this section exists on all resources).

The actual command you'll need is:

`pulumi import azure-native:storage:Blob myresource1 /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/blobServices/default/containers/{containerName}/blobs/{blobName}`